# How to make line feed code valid

Tags: symfony, twig

I have entity like

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text",nullable=true)
 *
 */

private $freeText;
```

then I fetch this column in php and put this in twig.

```
{{ freeText }}
```

But it ignores the line feed code.

I think I have to change line feed code to 'br' tag though,where and how should I do this?

Is there any special function on twig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you mean that even if you put newlines in your text, the browser ignores it and displays text in the same line. Yes, you'll need to replace `\n` characters with `<br />` tags, there's a [filter for that](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/nl2br.html):

```
{{ "I like Twig.\nYou will like it too."|nl2br }}
{# outputs

    I like Twig.<br />
    You will like it too.

#}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the string is being [(auto)escaped](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html) ... try:

```
{{ var|raw }} {# var won't be escaped #}
```

... or ...

```
{% autoescape false %}
   {{ var }}
{% endautoescape %}
```